# Почтовый клиент для устройств Apple?

Tags: ios, macos, iphone, email, ipad

По существу моей работы, мне необходимо пользоваться различными аккаунтами электронной почты. Очень нравится Apple Mail и на нем у меня основные ящики настроены, как личные, так и рабочие. Но есть ящики, нужные, которыми пользуюсь для подработок и в Apple Mail их не добавишь по ряду причин.

Посоветуйте, какими программами пользуетесь Вы? Мне нравится простота визуального оформления, мне не нужны всякие плюшки, напоминалки, добавки в календарь. Мне нужно чтобы программа работала с почтой по imap, работала стабильно и качественно, без зависонов. Чтобы мою переписку не смогли прочитать, потому что у разработчика сервисы и руки кривые (шифровать и скрываться тут не причем именно бэкэенд функционал приложения). Ну и хорошо, если программа есть для различных устройств от Apple, не обязательно, но хотелось бы, но главное, чтобы была для macOS.

- В свое время пробовал Spark, но у него проблемы с простой настройкой к почте Яндекса. Всегда танцы с бубном, ключами доступа и т.п.
- Очень долго время использовал купленный Airmail 3, но эти гады, вместо того, чтобы выпустить отдельной программой Airmail 4, тупо обновили Airmail 3 до версии 4 и заманивают на покупку "подписки". Запускает по иконке Airmail 3, в "о программе" версия 4 и постоянно просит ее купить мол куча плюшек новых - нафиг не надо! И так интерфейс перегруженный и плюшек дофига ненужных. В общем огорчили меня, поэтому и занялся поиском.
- Установил себе Postbox. Дизайн нравится, но работает через раз и медленно. Прям бы и оставил его (потому что остальные программы из моего списка нижа по всем другим параметрам хуже), но разработчик просит за программу $29 в год или $50 навсегда, а это примерно 2200 рублей в год или 3800 рублей единоразово. Причем у Postbox не сказать чтобы какого-то функционала было за такие деньги. Опять же, плюшек мне не надо, но за письма-собиралку 4кР многовато. В общем дороговато, но если альтернативы не найду, это пока первый кандидат.
- Outlook? Это самый жуткий интерфейс что я увидел из почтовых программ! Особенно в этот момент у меня включилась по расписанию "темная тема" мак - ненене, это не то.
- Canary Mail - я не помню уже почему его удалил. Вроде тоже не мог подключиться без ключей к яндекс почте и что-то еще было. Прожил у меня на компе пару дней.
- Polymail - где-то читал, что с безопасностью писем тут проблемы. Опять же подписка. Сволочи! Дайте купить и пользоваться 10 лет))
- Mozila Thunderbird - дизайн морально устарел, моя дизайнерская часть не смогла выдержать больше часа использования этого чуда.
- eM Client - простой, работает, но опять подписка...

Ну наверное больше вариантов то и нет, но вдруг публика знает и другие приложения? Подскажите, а?